# android ImageView разметка

Tags: android, xml, изображения, разметка

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, можно ли используя только лишь Layout-ы, не используя Surface, Canvas и прочее, сделать подобное ( см. аттач )? Имеется ввиду именно расположение контроллов с поддержкой landscape. Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. Нужна комбинация 5-6 (может и больше) вложенных друг в друга лейаутов.

На верхнем уровне `LinearLayout` с горизонтальной ориентацией, далее в него 2 вложенных `LinearLayout` один с аватаркой, а второй (справа) содержащий все остальное.

В правом надо будет организовать `RelativeLayout`, где слева большой `ImageView` а справа снизу `Button`. Мелкие `ImageView` сгруппировать в `TableView` с двумя строчками, в каждой строчке еще по одному `RelativeLayout`

Это как бы версия, возможно она не сработает, а может и сработает. Но смысл простой - комбинацией различных типов лейаутов всегда можно нарисовать практически все что угодно. Еще ни разу не было, чтобы я не смог нарисовать какой угодно сложный набор.

Дерзайте.

**Update**
Большой круг с фотиком можно например сделать так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Где `drawable/ball`:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/sky_blue"/>
    <size
        android:width="12dp"
        android:height="12dp"/>
</shape>
```

В итоге получится примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: здесь проблема в том,как сделать позиционирование в непрямоугольных пересечениях элементов, например большой круг и тот,что с фотоаппаратом. Можно попробовать наложение `FrameLayout`, но с его позиционированием тоже будут проблемы. Без этого фотоаппарата можно было бы собрать разметку довольно легко

Comment: `RelativeLayout` позволяет накладывать фигуры друг на друга - с ним обычно проблема как сделать, чтобы фигуры не пересекались друг с другом. Так что больших проблем не вижу.

Comment: См. апдейт с примером решения проблемы обозначенной @pavlofff

Comment: Да, я вот сейчас попробовал - действительно `RealativeLayout` позволяет накладывать виджеты, я даже как то и не задумывался об этом .. Тогда хочу спросить - зачем так много вложенных контейнеров ? Ведь тогда все можно спозиционировать всего в одном `RealativeLayout` , а то HierarchyViewer с ума сойдет :)

Comment: На самом то деле `HierarchyViewer` сойдет с ума когда все сгруппировано в одном `RelativeLayout` - не помню уж где но читал что так делать не айс. К тому же опыт показывает, что все сгруппировать в одном `RelativeLayout` не всегда удобно получается.

Answer (score 2):

А можно и без 5-6 наложений, надо всего лишь использовать RelativeLayout.
Делал [на скорую руку](http://cs5.pikabu.ru/images/previews_comm/2015-04_2/14283943512500.jpg), так что сильно не пинайте.

**Update**

Для этих кругов используйте стиль из ответа @Barmaley и подключайте его через `android:background`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Коренной элемент. Ширина (150dip) дана случайная. -->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:padding="8dip" >
    <!-- Надпись "Аватарка" -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Аватарка"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <!-- Кнопка "Загрузить фото" -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Загрузить\nфото"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>
    <!-- Контейнер для аватарки, осталось сделать круглый стиль.
        Размер дан случайный. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF" />
    <!-- Кнопка с камерой. Осталось сделать круглый стиль
        и найти иконку. Размер дан случайный. -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF"
        android:layout_above="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar" />
    <!-- Голубой круг. Осталось сделать круглый стиль.
        Размер дан случайный. Можно использовать ImageView вместо View. -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="15dip"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/camera" />
    <!-- Голубой круг. Осталось сделать круглый стиль.
        Размер дан случайный. Можно использовать ImageView вместо View. -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="15dip"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Результат (без стилей) выглядит так:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: большое спасибо, ребят, что откликнулись.. и собственно за предложенные решения тоже большое спасибо..